# Using Orange 3 association rules in Python (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, orange, orange-api

so I am trying to using association rules in Orange. I do understand that moving from Orange 2 to Orange 3, association rules became an addon.

So I added it and managed to use in the GUIs. But I am not sure how to use it for jupyter notebook. This [link](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/2/reference/rst/Orange.associate.html) is a documentation provided by Orange on how it can be used in Python, But it is a 2.7 documentation.

I checked the documentation for Orange 3 and I could not find any reference to the association or how to use an add-on in general.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the scripting [documentation for Orange3-Associate](https://orange3-associate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html) add-on.

Comment: The documentation is helpful if you are using one of orange datasets. However there are no details whatsoever on how to convert your own dataset into an orange table. Thanks for the informative sharing, it might be helpful for others but not in my particular case.

Comment: There's also a reference [further down the page](https://orange3-associate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html#fpgrowth.association_rules) with an example based on boolean NumPy matrix ...

Answer (score 0):

Simple prepare a data file like this, and import with `Table.from_file`.
https://datasets.biolab.si/core/foodmart.basket